# Can two inertial frames of reference detect which one has zero constant speed through calculating strength of a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, inertial-frames

So we've learnt about inertial frames of reference (which I'm not sure I understand fully) and quoting our teacher: "you cannot devise an experiment to distinguish between two inertial frames of reference". Now we're studying electromagnetism and he pointed out (in passing) that a current creates a magnetic field but static electricity doesn't. So the difference seems to be just movement and not acceleration, from what I understand (I'm pretty sure there's gotta be something wrong about this).

Now my question is this: can't we determine between two inertial frames of reference, which one has zero constant speed and which one has positive constant speed if the magnetic field is stronger (or exists) for the one that has positive constant speed? so that both measure the magnetic field created by a charged particle, one observer has zero constant speed relative to the charged particle and the other has a positive constant speed; presumably the first observer would see no magnetic field and second observer would detect a magnetic field, showing that he is indeed moving compared to the charged particle as opposed to the second observer, hence distinguishing between the two frames.

Now my understanding of the subject is on the level of the one class that we've had on electromagnetism so far, so this all might sound very stupid (specially about movement creating magnetic field for static charge, which I'm not sure I understood it correctly) but I couldn't find any similar questions and I had to ask; so a high school level explanation is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: How can you tell if you are moving or if the charge is moving?

Comment: Ah, I suppose I can't; so that would mean the person measuring no magnetic field is in the same reference frame with the charge then? But can't this still mean that a person detecting a magnetic field has different velocity and therefore distinguishable from the other one? But that's the same thing as two frames measuring different values for each other. I guess I really don't know what I'm not understanding here.

Comment: Your initial statement isn't correct, so I'll let you fix it before I try to tease out the real question here.  You say, "you cannot ... distinguish between two inertial frames". But you can. If I'm in one frame and I watch something go by me at constant speed, I can see that it is a separate frame. Therefore I have distinguished between two different inertial frames, all with different x, y, z, vx, vy, vz. I assume you know this too. So what's the real statement about inertial frames?

Comment: the "problem" with inertail frames being equally valid is that there is no absolute reference frame relative to whom one could define stationary. If you are stationary in some inertial frame, there is always another inertial frame in which you are not stationary.

Comment: I guess Jonas answered tom's question before I could; but yeah my understanding is that all inertial frames are relative to eachother so there's no one that can decide between them whether one is stationary or not. I realize that the problem is with my understanding of the relativity principle. So the problem with my original question is that there's still no objective outsider that can say that observer a is the one that is right in measuring no magnetic field because he himself has either a constant velocity relative to him and would measure a field or would have a parallel equal velocity.